# Is there a difference between "this" and "that" in French?

Tags: usage, pronoms, démonstratifs

I've noticed when reading sometimes that "*c'est*" is used for both "this is" and "that is" and I was wondering as to whether that applied to "*ce*", "*cette*", and "*cet*".

Comment: Are you talking about the *this* and *that* used with verbs or the ones used with nouns? In French, these are different words.

Comment: **c'est** is also used for **it's**

Comment: The use of deitic pronouns is a very complex subject. Deixis and deitic pronouns/adjectives is the correct way to refer to these words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can assure you that there's no difference as per the usage of "c'est/ce/cet/cette". As a native french speaker, I've always struggled to understand the difference between this and that, and I'm still often making mistakes when I speak english since I'd use "ce" for everything in French.

However:

- If you want to stress a "this", you should use "celui-ci" ("celle-ci" f.), which means "this one"
- If you want to stress a "that", you should use "celui-là" ("celle-là" f.), which means "that one"

But these expressions would rather be used when there is a confusion between designated subjects, as an answer to "which one ?".

Comment: C'est is definitely **not** interchangeable with ce/cet and cette.

Comment: Also, you could translate "**that is** very strange" (when stressed on **that**) with "**ça c'est** très étrange"

Comment: "I've always struggled to understand the difference" — ah, vraiment? Moi, j'ai toujours fait correspondre "this" = "ceci" puis "that" = "cela" dans ma tête alors je suis surprise d'apprendre que ce ne soit pas aussi clair que je pensais. (En passant, en japonais on ne compte pas deux, mais trois mots dans cette catégorie alors c'est encore plus compliqué!)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on a évacué les formes neutres ceci/cela ; ce sont ces formes qu'on substitue à _ce_, et qui servent vraiment à appuyer. On n'indique pas que _c'est_ contient le pronom démonstratif _ce_. On ne fait pas la nuance entre le pronom et le déterminant démonstratif. On ne traite pas de la composition des pronoms ce+ici/là ou de l'aspect prochain/lointain ; on ne dispose pas des nuances quand on utilise un pronom seul ou en paire. On ne fait pas allusion au fait qu'à l'oral la forme lointaine l'emporte sur la forme prochaine. La première phrase ne fait aucun sens. Merci.

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette le *ce* de *c'est* n'apparait qu'avec le verbe être d'où ma question à l'auteur initial. De leur côté *ceci*, *cela* et *ça* apparaissent librement avec tous les verbes... Et ces éléments sont très différents du déterminant démonstratif *ce/cet/cette/ces*. De quelle première phrase est-il question dans la conclusion ?

Comment: *C'est* is not interchangeable with *ce*/*cet*/*cette* as Joze said. Plus *celui-ci* and *celle-ci* can't always be used to mean *this* and *that*: *There is noone here, this is very strange. But there used to be people here, and that is even more strange*. You would say *c'est très étrange* and *ça, c'est encore plus étrange*. Or as some people said: *ceci est très étrange* and *cela est encore plus étrange*.

Comment: @Random You're wrong. In your example "ça, c'est très étrange", the "c" from "c'est" is a repetition of "ça", and "ça" is a contraction of "cela". So if you translate it in english, it is "This, it is very strange".

Comment: @AlFonce I don't agree. If I want to emphasis "ça", I would say "ça, c'est très étrange", because you can't emphasis " c' " alone, so you add "ça", even if it makes a repetition, In english, you can easily emphasis on "that", so you don't have to add "it" as in french...

Answer (score 6):

Many wrong or partially wrong answers here, and your question is not precise enough. The use of demonstrative pronouns is not easy. Here are my thoughts after I've read the answers, probably not exhaustive.

Note the use of *ci* and *là* in French:

- Ici = here
- Là = there
- Celui-ci/celle-ci = this one
- Celui-là/celle-là = that one
- Ceux-ci/celles-ci = these ones
- Ceux-là/celles-là = those ones

Now let's begin.

- *This* + noun for *ce*/*cet*/*cette* + noun

> I want this balloon!
>
> Je veux ce ballon !

If you want to insist more:

> Je veux ce ballon-ci !

It means not another one, this one.

- *That* for *ce*/*cet*/*cette*

> No, I want that one! That ballon!
>
> Non, je veux celui-là ! Ce ballon-là !

- *This* in *this is*

If you say:

> It's a beautiful dress!

You translate it into:

> C'est une belle robe !

But if you say:

> This is a beautiful dress!

You probably want to insist on *this* dress, so you could say:

> Cette robe est belle !
>
> Cette robe-ci est belle !

- *That* in *that is*

> That is a beautiful dress!

Could be translated into:

> Cette robe-là est belle !

But we would rather say:

> Ça, c'est une belle robe !

In many cases, you can't use *-là* to translate *that*:

> That is something!
>
> Ça, c'est quelque chose !
>
> That is strange.
>
> Ça, c'est bizarre.

- Example

> This building is empty. It's strange. Yeah, this is really strange. But the strangest thing is that it is closed. *That* is very strange.
>
> Cet immeuble est vide. C'est bizarre. Ouais, c'est vraiment bizarre. Mais la chose la plus bizarre c'est qu'il est fermé. Ça, c'est vraiment bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to say "this right here is," you can say "Ceci est...".

Likewise, if you want to emphasize "that thing over there," you can say, "Cela est..."

Both of these constructions are more characteristic of written French (and formal spoken French, like a newscast or a pre-written speech) than the everyday language.

Answer (score 2):

## La différence entre *ceci* et *cela* est une notion de proximité

On emploie de préférence *ceci* pour désigner quelque chose de proche, et par opposition, *cela* pour désigner quelque chose de plus éloigné.

C'est vrai pour un éloignement géographique mais aussi préférentiel : si mon choix se porte plutôt sur un bonbon à la fraise plutôt qu'un autre bonbon à la framboise, j'utiliserais *celui-ci* pour désigner le bonbon à la fraise, et *celui-là* pour le bonbon à la framboise.

Pour s'en souvenir facilement, il suffit de revenir à l'origine de ces expressions :

- *Ceci* => *Celui-ci* (ou *celle-ci) renvoie au mot *ici*.
- *Cela* => *Celui-là* (ou *celle-là) renvoie à l'expression *là-bas*.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis d'accord avec Jean.

I replace could with should as....

If you want to stress a "this", **you should use** "celui-ci" ("celle-ci" f.), which means "this one"

If you want to stress a "that", **you should use** "celui-là" ("celle-là" f.), which means "that one"

Comment: Oh, really? *This is a really nice day!* = *Celle-ci est vraiment une belle journée !*? No way.